# PyCharm does not show suggestion for Selenium driver in pageObject class

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, appium

[image]I am working on a simple project using PyCharm and Selenium. I am trying to apply the page object pattern. My problem is that I do not get an autosuggestion when typing `self.driver`. After the `.` I should see suggestions, but I am not; however if I were to run the program, it would run without a problem.

[image]

On the second screenshot, i should also get autosuggestions but i am not Let me know your comments on this.

Comment: check your selenium lib present under lib/site-packages under python folder

Comment: where is that folder? what exactly should i look for in there?

Comment: its available in your python folder

Comment: what do you want me to see or not see inside that folder?

Comment: selenium lib should be present under this site-packages folder

Comment: i only see the folder python, but it does not contain that lib, i am using python3.7 as project interpreter

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/211756/discussion-between-adrian-jimenez-and-dipak-bachhav).

Answer (score 0):

When installing Selenium many folder are installed in the pythonxxx folder. Keep the folder `Lib > site-package > Selenium` and delete the other Selenium folder in python.

Comment: i already did and no luck, if i get the suggestion but only in the class where the driver is delcared, see the screenshot.